# Manipulate not showing anything

Tags: manipulate

This works:

```
Manipulate[Plot[2*x + 3*y, {x, 3, 4}], {y, 3, 4}]
```

But this doesn't

```
f=2*x + 3*y
Manipulate[Plot[f, {x, 3, 4}], {y, 3, 4}]
```

My "f" is a painful long expression so I'd rather be able to get the latter method to work  than work with the former.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Manipulate` has to 'see' the that f depends on  `y`, so define it as follows:

```
f[x_, y_] = 2*x + 3*y
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, y], {x, 3, 4}], {y, 3, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By the way, this is mentioned in the "Possible Issues" section of the `Manipulate`doc page.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. That saved me a ton of time. I usually  look at "More Information" and all the options and examples but I don't always look at "possible issues". I will keep it in mind to check it every time from now on. Thx.