# Manipulating a damped oscillator plot - plot does not show

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I was trying to make an oscillation plot that could be manipulated depending on the value of $\beta$. The differential equation is below, and when I just plot the solution, it turns out to be the correct plot. However, when I insert the manipulate function, the plot returns a blank graph. Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

```
    s = DSolve[{x''[t] + 2 β x'[t] + 4 x[t] == 0, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 1}, x[t], t];

Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 0, 5}], {β, 0, 4, 0.1}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulate not showing anything](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9985/manipulate-not-showing-anything)

Comment: It's the same essential problem, @xzczd, but I decided not to close it because there was another issue that I wanted to alert the OP to - see my answer. Happy to be overruled by the community if it comes to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues going on here, though only one of them is preventing your plot from working in the `Manipulate`.

The first is, as noted by xzczd in comments, that you need to get Mathematica to see that the `\[Beta]` in the expression for `x[t]/. s` is the same one you are using as the variable to be manipulated. You can see this is an issue with a slight variant to your `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[Table[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 0, 4, 2}]], {\[Beta], 0, 4, 0.1}]
```

[image]

You can ensure this using a second replacement rule, like this:

```
Manipulate[Grid[Table[
   Simplify[Evaluate[x[t] /. s] /. \[Beta] -> b], {t, 0, 4, 2}]], {b, 0, 4, 0.1}]
```

[image]

The second is that there are trivial imaginary parts here, though in this case they don't seem to matter for the plot. If you ever hit this in a more material way, you can use `Chop` to get rid of them.

Here's the code that gets you the plot.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s /. \[Beta] -> b], {t, 0, 4}], {b, 0, 4, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the answer:

```
Manipulate[Plot[
 Evaluate[x[t] /. NDSolve[{x''[t] + 2 \[Beta] x'[t] + 4 x[t]== 0, 
  x'[0] ==   0, x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 4}]],
  {t, 0, 5}], {\[Beta], 0,4,0.1}]
```

thank you for asking

Comment: It may be useful for the OP if you also pointed out the difference between your method and theirs, and why their method does not produce the desired plot.