Using the result of NDSolve to make animation
I have solved a system of PDEs and made density plots using the following script
  L = 5; del = 0.6; g = -0.1; a = 4; s = 0.1; tmax = 3;

ux = s (1 + 0.1   Exp[-(2.5)^2] - m[x, t]);
eqs = {2 s  k[x, t]  m[x, t] -  D[D[k[x, t], {x, 2}], t] + 
    2  s  del D[m[x, t], {x, 2}] == 
   0, -D[m[x, t], t] +  D[m[x, t], {x, 2}] + g  m[x, t]^3 + 
    m[x, t]  (a - ux + del  D[k[x, t], t]) == 0}; bc = {k[0, t] == 0, 
  k[L, t] == 0, m[0, t] == 1 + 0.1  Exp[-(2.5)^2], 
  m[L, t] == 1 + 0.1  Exp[-(2.5)^2]}; ic = {m[x, 0] == 
   1 + 0.1  Exp[-(x - 2.5)^2]};

sol = NDSolveValue[{eqs, ic, bc, k[x, 0] == 0}, {m[x, t], 
    k[x, t]}, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MaxPoints" -> 401, "MinPoints" -> 401, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}];

Then I tried to make an animation out of it using Animate as follows
Animate[Plot[sol[[2]], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImagePadding -> 20, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, tmax}]

However, this gives me a white plot without any graph. Could someone please help me how to solve this?
Edit:
I have managed to plot this using the comments. But I realized I need to plot $H$ where $\partial_x^2 H(x,t)=sol[[2]][x,t] $ where the animation dynamics is given by $t$.
I tried to do this using
solH = NDSolveValue[{D[H[x, t], {x, 2}] == solb[[2]][x, t], 
    H[L, t] == 0, H[0, t] == 0}, {H}, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MaxPoints" -> 401, "MinPoints" -> 401, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}];
Animate[Plot[solH[[1]][x, t], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImagePadding -> 20, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, tmax}]

But I get an error that I don't understand:

NDSolveValue::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.


Please post the full code or another Minimal Working Example.

@cvgmt added a code

One way is Animate[Plot[sol[[2]] /. t -> s, {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All,    ImagePadding -> 20, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {s, 0, tmax}] or Animate[Plot[With[{t = t}, sol[[2]]], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All,    ImagePadding -> 20, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, tmax}], but I don't know the reasion.

This explains the cause (localization) of the problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9985/manipulate-not-showing-anything . Note Animate constructs a special Manipulate.

This fixes in this case is (1)remove variables in output of NDSolveValue: sol = NDSolveValue[{eqs, ic, bc, k[x, 0] == 0}, {m, k},...]; and (2) to put the variables in the plot: Animate[Plot[sol[[2]][x, t],...].

@Goofy Thank you very much. Is there any chance you know how to plot the edit? If you could post your answer I can accept is as a correct answer

@cvgmt Thank you very much. I realized I had missed something in my question. so I added an edit.

The issue is similar to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/manipulate-and-turning-expressions-into-functions. The problem with finding a universal duplicate seems to be that while the cause is the same (the way Manipulate localizes variables), the fix in each case can vary, depending on how the global variable is used. It would be nice if somehow users could find a solution to their problem more easily. The answer already exists, in a sense, but it's hard to find and adapt.

Thanks, questionerno8. There are errors from NDSolve with the updated system that have to do with how the PDE is specified. It seems something is missing. I made some remarks about this at the end of my answer.

What's the error message? solb is undefined, so I'm not surprised. In the line above the code it's supposed to be sol. I assume the b is typo. I'll add the message I get under that assumption, so that readers can respond.

Here is the fix from my comment, which moves the variables x and t from being global and external to Animate to be local and internal:
L = 5; del = 0.6; g = -0.1; a = 4; s = 0.1; tmax = 3;

ux = s  (1 + 0.1    Exp[-(2.5)^2] - m[x, t]);
eqs = {2  s   k[x, t]   m[x, t] - D[D[k[x, t], {x, 2}], t] + 
    2   s   del  D[m[x, t], {x, 2}] == 
   0, -D[m[x, t], t] + D[m[x, t], {x, 2}] + g   m[x, t]^3 + 
    m[x, t]   (a - ux + del   D[k[x, t], t]) == 0}; bc = {k[0, t] == 
   0, k[L, t] == 0, m[0, t] == 1 + 0.1   Exp[-(2.5)^2], 
  m[L, t] == 1 + 0.1   Exp[-(2.5)^2]}; ic = {m[x, 0] == 
   1 + 0.1   Exp[-(x - 2.5)^2]};

sol = NDSolveValue[{eqs, ic, bc, k[x, 0] == 0}, {m, k}, {x, 0, L}, {t,
    0, tmax}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> 401, "MinPoints" -> 401, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}]

Animate[Plot[sol[[2]][x, t], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.5}}, 
  ImagePadding -> 20, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, tmax}]


I think the updated question about H[x, t] should probably be a second question.  The issue with H seems to be an incompletely formulated PDE system. (NDSolve complains about boundary and initial conditions.)  The issues with it seem to have nothing to do with Animate or plotting, at least until NDSolve is working. Possibly, the following is the answer (assuming solb is the same as sol, since no solb appears in the OP):
solH = Head@Integrate[sol[[2]][x, t], x, x];
solH = Function[{x, t}, Evaluate[solH[x, t] - solH[5, t] x/5]]

Animate[Plot[solH[x, t], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> {All, {-0.65, 0.02}},
   ImagePadding -> 20, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, tmax}]


Thanks. The solution to H seems to be incorrect as it is not symmetric about the center of the box

@questionerno8 It occurred to me that if one just thinks about it for a minute, it's easy to adjust to the BCs. See updated answer.

aw, nice! @goofy

The problem is the localization of t inside Manipulate. The "t" in sol is not the same "t" in Manipulate. Therefore Manipulate does NOT replace the "t" of sol by a number. You may sees this by:
fun := (Print[t]; sol[[2]]);
Manipulate[Plot[fun, {x, 0, L}], {t, 0, tmax}]

This prints "y" many times.
To fix this you may either inject the "t" from Manipulate into sol[[2]] using "With":
Animate[Plot[With[{t = t}, sol[[2]]], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImagePadding -> 20, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, tmax}]

Or you may define a new function that will do the same:
fun[x_, t_] = sol[[2]];
Animate[Plot[fun[x, t], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImagePadding -> 20, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, tmax}]

