Animate does not work with Interpolating Function
I have an Interpolating Function T[t] (calculated as a solution to a DE).
The following statements work just fine (where the a, r and tm have previously assigned numerical values and T[t] is an InterpolatingFunction also previously calculated as a solution to a DE)
X1 = r*Sin[T[t]+a]
Animate[Graphics[{Line[{{0,0},{%,-r*Cos[T[t]+a]}}]}],{t,0,tm}]
Animate[Graphics[{Line[{{0,0},{r*Sin[T[t]+a],-r*Cos[T[t]+a]}}]}],{t,0,tm}]

There % refers to r*Sin[T[t]+a]
But the following DOES NOT work
X1 = r*Sin[T[t]+a]
Animate[Graphics[{Line[{{0,0},{X1,-r*Cos[T[t]+a]}}]}],{t,0,tm}]

Is there a way to make this work without using % or explicitly typing in r*Sin[T[t]+a] ?

You pretty much have the same problem as here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/303244/using-the-result-of-ndsolve-to-make-animation.  See if the comments and answers there help.

Does this work: x2[t_] = r Sin[T[t] + a]; Animate[Graphics[{Line[{{0,0},{x2[t],-r*Cos[T[t]+a]}}]}],{t,0,tm}]

No it does not work, now have  "Tag Times in (Sqrt[2] Sin[[Theta][t]])[t_] is Protected" message, but having % still works.

Animate has the HoldAll attribute. You can search for that in the documentation or on this site. One thing you can do is use Evaluate: Animate[Evaluate[   Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {X1, -r*Cos[T[t] + a]}}]}]], {t, 0, tm}]. Another option is to use With: With[{X1 = r*Sin[T[t] + a]},   Animate[Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {X1, -r*Cos[T[t] + a]}}]}], {t, 0,     tm}]]

Fantastic, both methods work. Evaluate is slightly more convenient.
